# Postgresql - Incorrect Sorting

Tags: postgresql, sorting, ubuntu, collation

I have a leads_lead table in the database and when I use the following query I get the results as shown below.

## Query

```
select name 
from leads_lead as ll 
where ll.branch_id = 14 
order by ll.name desc;
```

## Results

```
           name            
---------------------------
 testing app 7
 testing app 4
 testing app 22
 testing app 22
 testing app 112
 testing app 10
 testing 9
 testing 6
 testing 5
 testing 3
 testing 2
 Usha Devi Kewat
 Uma kumari tharu
 Tulsiram Yadav
 Triveni Chaudhary
 Testing From APP
 Testing
 Testing
 Testing
 Test Time
 .....
 .....
```

But the sorting is not correct. Is this some bug in PostgreSQL?
I'm using Postgres 13.3 in Ubuntu server 20.04.1 and encoding is UTF8.

Comment: How is the sorting incorrect?

Comment: You could define a custom function and `order by func(ll.name) desc`.

Comment: Which order did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have your database created with the `C` collation, which sorts according to code point.

But you can specify other collations, for example

```
ORDER BY ll.name COLLATE "en_US" DESC
```

You have to use a collation that is defined in your database, see `pg_collation` for the list.

Comment: Yes. You are right. My db's collation is C.UTF8. I fixed this with creating new db with en_US.UTF8 collation and migrated data to new db. Thanks.